# Access 2013 was unable to export parameter query to XML and XSD

Tags: xml, ms-access, vba, ms-access-2013

I'm currently trying to write the VBA to do the XML but since it was failing, I decided to try the built in XML generator that comes with Access.  I have a parameterized query and after I put in the parameters, I go to export the XML and XSD files.  After clicking OK, I get a popup saying that "Access was unable to export the data."  It works fine on non-parameterized queries so I don't think its a DLL issue.  Any thoughts would be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to recreate your issue in Access 2010. Interestingly, Access could successfully export the parameter query to the XML file alone, but trying to export both the XML and XSD files caused Access to choke.

A workaround would be to use `SELECT * INTO ...` to dump the query results to a temporary table, export the table to XML and XSD, and then drop the temporary table:

```vbs
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Sub so37834736()
    ' sample data
    Const queryName = "myParameterQuery"
    Const tempTableName = "zzzTempTable"
    Const xmlFileSpec = "C:\__tmp\zzzTest.xml"
    Const xsdFileSpec = "C:\__tmp\zzzTest.xsd"

    Dim cdb As DAO.Database
    Set cdb = CurrentDb
    Dim qdf As DAO.QueryDef
    Set qdf = cdb.CreateQueryDef("", _
            "SELECT * INTO [" & tempTableName & "] FROM [" & queryName & "]")
    qdf!prmStartDate = DateSerial(2001, 1, 1)  ' specify parameter value(s)
    qdf.Execute dbFailOnError
    Set qdf = Nothing
    Set cdb = Nothing
    Application.ExportXML acExportTable, tempTableName, xmlFileSpec, xsdFileSpec
    DoCmd.DeleteObject acTable, tempTableName
End Sub
```

Comment: Yea that does seem to work, I ended up modifying the on click event to intercept the parameters and then store the query into a temp table.  Same concept as yours